# ErrorCode: TargetDiskBlobAlreadyExists

Tags: virtual-machine, powershell, vhd, azure

I am creating an AzureRM VM using existing VHD, the error which I received is

```
New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Location $loc -VM $vm
New-AzureRmVM : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'.
StartTime: 4/18/2016 3:38:49 PM
EndTime: 4/18/2016 3:38:50 PM
OperationID: a99cdc43-366c-4a02-8ca9-2cfca79de8e3
Status: Failed
ErrorCode: TargetDiskBlobAlreadyExists
ErrorMessage: Blob https://*******.blob.core.windows.net/essrestore/Kel-DC01201611012647.vhd already exists. Please provide a different blob URI as target 
for disk 'KELDC1_osDisk'.
At line:2 char:1
+ New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Location $loc -VM $vm
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I got this resolved, i have created new blob and was able to deploy new VM with existing VHD.




Appreciate your support. :)

Comment: Might be a good idea to post the answer for future reference for other users :)

Comment: Make sure the VHD is copied to the new Container and while deploying the VM you should the container path 
for eg:- $osDiskVhdUri = "https://*****.blob.core.windows.net/essrestore/Kel-FonSrv201611217334.vhd"

this will install a new VM using your existing VHD.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new blob and deploy new a VM with the existing VHD. Make sure the VHD is copied to the new Container, and while deploying the VM you should specify the container path, for example:

```
$osDiskVhdUri = "https://*****.blob.core.windows.net/essrestore/Kel-FonSrv201611217334.vhd"
```

This will install a new VM using your existing VHD.